# onclick event to call javascript using struts tags

Tags: javascript

i am trying to call onclick event on a button, and i have used struts tags as well in my code, when i try to click button, onclick event is not getting fired. Below is the code. Help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in Advance

```
function validateUser(){
  alert("Hi");

  $.ajax({
    traditional: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajaxlogin.action?username='+$('username').val()+'&password='+$('password').val(),
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data){
      console.log(stringify(data));
    }
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="section" id="section1">
      <div class="login-form">
        <s:form  method=""  action="" cssClass="form-wrapper-01">
          <s:textfield theme="simple" cssClass="inputbox email" id="username"   name="username" placeholder="User Name" /> 
          <s:password theme="simple" cssClass="inputbox password" id="" name="password" placeholder="Password" />

          <p><s:submit theme="simple" cssClass="button" id="button" value="SIGN IN" onclick="validateUser()" /></p>

        </s:form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <p><s:submit theme="simple" cssClass="button" id="button" value="SIGN IN" onclick="validateUser()" /></p>